# CoreLocation CLLocationManager requestLocation takes 10 seconds to get a callback

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I am trying to get the user location to plot it on a map in real time. I am using the following method.

```
[self.locationManager requestLocation];
```

However the callback for this which appears in locationManager didUpdateLocations takes approximately 10 seconds to return. Is this just a limit of the OS, or is there a faster way to get a callback for my current user location? If this is a limit I can't get around, will my locations always be 10 seconds in the past? If the user is riding a bike, will their location always be lagging several feet behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`requestLocation` tries to find an accurate location based on the `desiredAccuracy` set in the location manager. If it can't find one before it times out (after 10 seconds) it will return the best location it could find.

Use `startUpdatingLocation` if you want to get continuous real-time location updates.